# How to get the difference of two values of same column in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

So I have table T in the Postgres database which has day to day values of the users. From that table, I need to find the difference between yesterday's value and today's value of an attribute C of all the users and return the IDs of the users' for which the difference is greater than 10.

Can this whole thing be done in one or two queries? The solutions I have in my mind are naive and will need separate queries for each user. Anything more efficient than this will be also great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the schema for table `T` this is just a shot in the dark. Here it goes:

```
WITH y_date AS (
    SELECT 
        user_id, c
    FROM 
        t
    WHERE 
        timestamp_fld::date = current_date - (interval - '1 day')
),
WITH t_date AS (
    SELECT 
        user_id, c
    FROM 
        t
    WHERE 
        timestamp_fld::date = current_date
)
SELECT 
   user_id
FROM 
   y_date
JOIN 
   t_date
ON
    y_date.user_id = t_date.user_id
WHERE
   abs(t_date.c - y_date.c) > 10
```

Using CTE(Common Table Expression) to pull the values for yesterday and today and then joining those results to get the absolute difference for each user and only return those that are greater then 10. The above is based on a bunch of assumptions. A better answer will depend on more information.

Comment: Worked for me after some modifications. Thanks.